# How can I make a fee Challan form and convert this fee in two equal installments of the same student roll no?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make an installment in fee for a student of university. therefore I want to make two fee challan slips from one fee Challan of the same student roll no.

**i want to do this mvc asp.net**

Forexample:

Original fee slip                                          //record in DB TABLE

```
   StudentName   RollNo      fee        status

       abc        1         1000        full
```

After Installment of fee                   // i want to do below

```
    StudentName  RollNo      fee        status

       abc         1         500       installment
       abc         1         500       installment
```

Answer (score 0):

your db is not optimised try googling ACID prop in db and from next time create a better db structure for this one i would say add one more column like and make it like this

> ```
> student name | Rollno | Fee | remaining amount | Status 
> abc             1      1000   1000               due
> cde          | 2      | 1000| 500              | instalment
> ```

your mvc part will be something like

```
if(m.status==due||m.status==Installment)
{
  if(m.remaining>= amountPaid)
    {
       m.remaining =m.remaining-amountPiad'
       m.remaining>0?m.status="Full":m.status="Installment";
       db.SaveChanges();
     }
else
     {
        decimal returnAmount = amountPaid - m.remaining;
         m.remaining =0;
         m.status="Full";
          db.saveChanges
         viewbag.Message ="Return change of" + returnAmount
      }
}
```

Comment: #RAHUL S R on which place i should paste this code with my own function parameter and table name..........i mean on which place i should do changes on view or model or controller.

Comment: RAHUL S R You do not make installment of fee please can you do that...?

Comment: you dont have to the remaining will work as the installment for rxample if you pay 200 rs instedad of 1000 it will take 200 and put as installment and put the rest in remaining '

Comment: where i should write this code in Controller or view?